# mongodb incremental numbering - 500 internal server error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to number the id's of my documents with node and mongodb.  I am getting a 500 internal server error: 'Cannot read property 'seq' of null.

// submit a ticket - this is returning a 500 error - not updating ID

```
router.post('/ticketform', function(req, res){
    var db = req.db;

function getNextSequence(name, callback){
    db.counters.findAndModify(
        {
            query:{ _id:name},
            update:{$inc:{seq:1} },
            new:true
        }, callback
    );
}

    getNextSequence('ticket', function(err, obj) {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        db.users.insert(
        {
            '_id': obj.seq,
            'firstname':req.body.firstname,
            'lastname':req.body.lastname,
            'email':req.body.email,
            'phone':req.body.phone,
            'issue':req.body.issue
        }, function(err,docs) {
            if (err) console.error(err);
            console.log(docs);
            res.end();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: [`findAndModify`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#find-and-modify) is async so it doesn't return its result, it provides it to a callback.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably referring to [this tutorial.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-optimistic-loop). In the example they are showing the implementation in the MongoDB shell, where findAndModify is synchronous. As JohnnyHK pointed in the comments, findAndModify in Node.js is asynchronous and the result is returned in the callback.

In Node.js you would do something like this:

```
function getNextSequence(name, callback){
    db.counters.findAndModify(
        { "_id": "ticket" },
        [],
        { "$inc": { "seq": 1 }},
        { "new": true, "upsert": true },
        callback
    );
}

getNextSequence('ticket', function(err, obj) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    db.users.insert(
    {
        '_id': obj.seq,
        'firstname':req.body.firstname,
        'lastname':req.body.lastname,
        'email':req.body.email,
        'phone':req.body.phone,
        'issue':req.body.issue
    }, function(err,docs) {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        console.log(docs);
        res.end();
    });
});
```

You should also check [the documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html#find-and-modify) for the command to better understand the options.

Comment: @MichaelSpatafore fixed my query

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using the node native driver in which the syntax is a bit different from the mongodb shell. The [`.findAndModify()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify) function in particular works quite differently.

As a complete working example for you to work into your application there is this code, along with the usage of the async module make the logic look a little cleaner:

```
var async = require("async"),
    mongodb = require("mongodb"),
    MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;


MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',function(err,db) {

    async.waterfall(
        [
            function(callback) {
                db.collection("counters").findAndModify(
                    { "_id": "ticket" },
                    [],
                    { "$inc": { "seq": 1 } },
                    { "upsert": true, "new": true },
                    function(err,doc) {
                        callback( err, doc.seq );
                    }
                );
            },
            function(seq, callback) {
                var doc = { "_id": seq };
                db.collection("users").insert(
                    { "_id": seq },
                    function(err, doc) {
                      callback( err, doc );
                    }
                );
            }
        ], function( err, result ) {

            console.log( result );
        }
    );
});
```

The parameters on the function are the "query", "sort" which is an array and required even if blank, then the "update" document, "options" in which you want the updated document returned as well as "upsert" to create a new document where no matching document exists,
 and finally the callback.

The async waterfall allows you to "pass through" results without embedding your functionality within the callback of the method you use to get the sequence. You don't need to do it that way, but the code looks a little cleaner and direct in it's purpose.

Alternately there are options such as mongoose if you want to use that which has a helper function in [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate). You might find connection management a little easier with that library, but it is up to you.